# Find the different value between each factor and plot the histogram in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am learning r and I want to build the histograms base on the revolution of each factor depend on the date in my dataframe.

Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")), 
  date=c("2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23","2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23","2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23"),
  total_bill = c(12.75,13.5,25.5,27.4,18.3,19.9,27.8,28.6,15.7,17.4,19.5,24.2)
)
```

My goal is to find for example: factor `Breakfast` I want to get the revolution of it like `13.5 - 12.75`,`25.5 - 13.5`,`27.4 - 25.5` and I want the same for `Lunch`, `Dinner` and then used those difference values to plot by using `ggplot` in 3 different graphs.

Any help for this would be much appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create do a group by difference

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    arrange(time, date) %>%
    group_by(time) %>% 
    mutate(Diff  = c(0, diff(total_bill)))  %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    filter(Diff != 0) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Diff, fill = time)) +
       geom_col()+ 
       facet_wrap(~ time)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more detail please I dont understand that. Is there a way to search in each group and minus those value to put in example another vector else

Comment: @Ben10 which one do you want top minus

Comment: @Ben10 do you need `dat %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(Diff  = c(0, diff(total_bill)))`

Comment: I want the different in each factor and the top on we dont know whatever it is in the same factor we calculate the different here is just the example

Comment: Can you purpose a way like for vector ```Breakfast``` after the minus we get for example breakfast=[0.75,12,1.9] and the same for lunch and dinner and purpose the way to plot the histogram please

Comment: @Ben10 so you want to filter out the 0 rows, right?

Comment: Yeah and plot the histogram by each factor

Comment: Yeah that's great and if I have the other date like date in ```Feb``` or ```March``` or whatever does this always adopted?

Comment: @Ben10 then the 'x' axis will be the month instead of the date

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Ben10 if you want to change the date format to month, use `+scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%B"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213728/discussion-between-ben10-and-akrun).